# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am trying to implement authentication in my MERN stack. After I fill the register form, it should direct me to login page, instead, am getting this error below. I will appreciate if anyone can help me. thanks

```js
xhr.js:220          POST http://localhost:5000/user/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:109
httpMethod @ Axios.js:144
wrap @ bind.js:9
signUp @ index.js:11
(anonymous) @ auth.js:18
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
handleSubmit @ register.js:25
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
auth.js:22 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}message: "Request failed with status code 500"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: {…}, status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}[[Prototype]]: Error
```

This is my router

```js
import express from "express";
import { signin, signup } from "../controllers/user.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signin', signin);
router.post('/signup', signup);


export default router;
```

This is my index.js for my server

```js
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
```

this is my frontend route

```js
import axios from "axios";
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'})

export const fetchPosts = () =>API.get('/posts');
export const createPost = (newPost) =>API.post('/posts', newPost);
export const updatePost = (id, updatedPost) =>API.patch(`/posts/${id}`, updatedPost);
export const deletePost = (id) =>API.delete(`/posts/${id}`);


export  const signIn = (values) => API.post('/user/signin', values)
export  const signUp = (values) => API.post('/user/signup', values)
```

Comment: Do you use jquery and react in the same project?

Comment: Do you have any logs on the server?  A 500 ('Request failed with status code 500') makes me believe it made the connection to the server and the server function failed.  Have you checked the 'signup' function on the server to make sure it's properly working?